Amazon Sagemaker is not able to recognize a hyperparameter in xgboost
I created an AWS notebook instance to classify churn and was trying to train the model:
hyperparameters = {
        "objective":"binary:logistic",
        "num_round":"50"}

estimator = XGBoost(entry_point = "train.py", 
                        framework_version='1.7-1',
                        hyperparameters=hyperparameters,
                        role=sagemaker.get_execution_role(),
                        instance_count=1,
                        instance_type='ml.m5.2xlarge',
                        output_path=output_path)

I'm getting this error
Parameter 'objective' should be one of these options

and the respective options for objective, in my case it's churn, so its either 0 or 1, so i've set it as
binary:logistic

which is a valid option, but i'm getting this error. How to resolve it?
I also tried setting the hyperparameters by using estimator.set_hyperparameters(), still the same error.

Can you also share the stacktrace and your train.py script? I assume that the error originates from the script, as XGBoost on SageMaker supports "binary:logistic" as objective in general
